# How to send multiple integer values using s.send in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, sockets

I have a client and a server. I am sending two integer values to server using s.send one after another.But my program gets stuck on server and not moves on.
Here is my client code.

```
import socket
s=socket.socket()
host=socket.gethostname()
port=8080
print("RSA Client Side \n")
p=int(input("Enter p(prime number) "))

q=int(input("Enter q(prime number) "))
n=p*q
print("First part of public key is %d"%n)
a=(p-1)*(q-1)
print("Euler Totient function is %d\n"%a)
e=int(input("Enter exponent e value such that 1<e<TF and is coprime "))
print("Public key is n=%d , e=%d\n"%(n,e))
s.connect((host, port))
s.send(str.encode(str(n)))
s.send(str.encode(str(e)))
m=int((s.recv(2048)).decode('utf-8'))
print("Recieved encrypted message is %d"%m)
s.close
```

and server code

```
 import socket
s=socket.socket()
host=socket.gethostname()
port=8080
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(5)
while 1:
    c,address=s.accept()
    n=int((c.recv(2048)).decode('utf-8'))
    e=int((c.recv(2048)).decode('utf-8'))
    print("Recieved public key from client is n=%d,e=%d\n"%(n,e))
    m=input("enter your message ")
    if m.isdigit():
        c=(m**e)%n
    print("Encrypted data send is %d\n"%m)
    c.send(str.encode(str(m)))
s.close
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have received all available data sent with `n=int((c.recv(2048)).decode('utf-8'))`; the consequenct `c.recv()` call *blocks waiting for data*.

Send both numbers together separated by a delimiter and split on that on the server side:

On the client:

```
s.sendall(str.encode("\n".join([str(n), str(e)])))
```

while on the server:

```
n, e = [int(i) for i in c.recv(2048).decode('utf-8').split('\n')]
```

in addition to that, you currently aren't closing the socket, you'll need to use `s.close()`.

Answer (score 2):

The first time you called `recv(2048)`, you most likely received both the `n` and `e` values run together - stream protocols like TCP do not preserve the boundaries between individual calls to `.send()`.  To send multiple values over a stream, YOU are entirely responsible for separating them at the receiving end.  Common strategies are to send data that is of a fixed length (and `.recv()` only that amount of data), or to separate them with a delimiter such as a newline character.

Answer (score 1):

** update I have written the code over and it works fine now, please take a look **

I apologize I'm on my phone atm, have you tried to pickle the data first and then just send the data as a serialized object then decode that object on client-side? [pickle docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html)
Also you could use Json and use json.dumps(), json.loads()

Client:

```
import socket
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host='LocalHost'

port=5300
print("RSA Client Side \n")
p=int(input("Enter p(prime number) "))

q=int(input("Enter q(prime number) "))
n=p*q
print("First part of public key is %d"%n)
a=(p-1)*(q-1)
print("Euler Totient function is %d\n"%a)
e=int(input("Enter exponent e value such that 1<e<TF and is coprime: "))
print("Public key is n=%d , e=%d\n"%(n,e))
s.connect((host, port))
s.send(str.encode(str(n)))
s.send(str.encode(str(e)))
m=int((s.recv(2048)).decode('utf-8'))
print("Recieved encrypted message is %d"%m)
s.close()
```

Server:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host='LocalHost'

port= 5300
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(5)

while True:
    c, address = s.accept()
    n = c.recv(2048)
    n = int(n)
    e = c.recv(2048)
    e = int(e)
    print("Recieved public key from client is n=%d,e=%d\n"%(n,e))
    m=input("enter your message ")
    if int(m):
        k=(m**e)%n

    print("Encrypted data send is %d\n"%m)
    c.send(str(m))
    c.close()
```

** keep in mind I changed the host/port and connection protocol along with some other things, on the server side you had c(m**e)%n the issue there is well, you overwrote the connection c, addr and turned it into and int and no longer a valid socket, few other bugs **

Comment: Ive ran the same code 10 times, it works for your question, but I believe at the end you send the wrong var m back to the client instead of what I defined as var k. If I didnt need to change your code I didnt.

Comment: I have copied the same code and ran it on my pc . Process stops after sending n.

Comment: I just ran it again lol, it works. What is the error your receiving?

Comment: That's something network side for you then. Same code runs on both my pc and laptop fine. Client regardless should give you and error since it's not listening the server is

Comment: Haha also I just thought about too and maybe thats what your seeing. When I first ran it it looks like client is hanging but if you go to server window, server is waiting for a raw_input response. Make sure thats filled out when prompted or client will hang waiting for server